# mod rewrite issue

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

in apache .htaccess file, i've write,

> RewriteRule ^animals$ index.php?type=animals

it redirects http://localhost/animals to  http://localhost/index.php?type=animals
and when the url typed as http://localhost/animals/ then the error occurs,
file not found.

what is the correct syntax to do the both http://localhost/animals and http://localhost/animals/ for redirecting to http://localhost/index.php?type=animals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is done with setthing this rule, if  the base is specified then all links get the base path

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `L` flag to mark the end of a rule and `QSA` to preserve new query parameters like this:

```
RewriteRule ^animals/?$ index.php?type=animals [L,QSA,NC]
```

NC is for no case comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^animals/?$ index.php?type=animals
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `RewriteRule ^animals/?$ index.php?type=animals`

Comment: the page opens in both `http://localhost/animals/` and `http://localhost/animals` but when i use `http://localhost/animals/` then css, js files does not loaded. but all works perfectly with using `http://localhost/animals`.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani you should code your html with all references to css and js files (and also links to other html pages) being absolute to your project path. So if your web is located at http://www.example.com/ all your links to files must be like `/css/style.css` instead of just `css/style.css`. If your page is at http://www.example.com/yoursite/ then all links must go like `/yoursite/css/style.css`

Comment: he is the rule `RewriteRule ^animals/?$ index.php?page=animals` and the directory is located at `http://localhost/zoo/` the requested page will be `http://localhost/zoo/animals` and `http://localhost/zoo/animals/` both when i use `http://localhost/zoo/animals` there is no problem all files get loaded and when i do `http://localhost/zoo/animals/` the page is loaded but no **js**, **css** files loaded, here is the jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/H9cvZ/24/

Comment: and ofcourse the .htaccess file is located at  `localhost/zoo/.htaccess`